# Alternating selector that depends on a sibling

Tags: html, css

I have html that looks somewhat like this:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>

    <div class="header">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
</div>
```

What i want to do is create a css that gives all even rows a background color. I've tested the nth-child(even) to try to get this result but as my css is applied to the .page the first group of header and rows are determining the order for the second groups coloring.

For example:

CSS:

```
.row:nth-child(even)
{
    background: red;
}
```

Then this is the result I get:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>    <--- Red
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>    <--- Red

    <div class="header">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>    <--- Red
    <div class="row">Text</div>
</div>
```

The seconds groups' first row is not colored, which is correct but not what I want to accomplish.

I want to create a css rule that colors rows dependent on the sibling .header instead of the parent .page, so no matter if the amount of rows in the first group is even or odd the first colored row in the second group should be row #1.

Edit 1:
I forgot to say that I want to be able to add/remove rows in both groups dynamically and the rules should still apply, thats why I cant color each row specifically.

Edit 2:
The HTML markup must stay the same, I can't nest the rows or something similar.

Comment: You can only do this without changing the markup if there will only ever be the exact same number of .row elements per .header.

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically add/remove rows

Comment: It s all time one header 3 rows ?

Comment: Then I suggest dividing each group of elements into their own sectioning elements.

Comment: @emisal Then you'd better wrap the rows in an extra element.

Comment: You can try `.page>div:nth-child(2n+1) {`

Comment: Can you set an upper limit to the number of rows in a header ?

Answer (score 6):

try

```
.header ~ .row:nth-child(even)
{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but I end up with no coloring on any rows at all.

Comment: Are you sure you didnt miss a whitespace or something? Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/05yxo8hx/

Comment: At first I was thinking about the same thing, but it wont work with different count of divs and will swap the colors http://jsbin.com/dicokicoju/1

Comment: I copied it directly so I don't think so, It might be that my PDF component don't support the tilde selector.

Comment: Maybe a browser issue

Comment: so maybe the most browser friedly solution would be to wrap the elements in another div

Answer (score 1):

Nest the rows

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">Text</div>
    <div>
      <div class="row">Text</div>
      <div class="row">Text</div>
      <div class="row">Text</div>
    </div>      

    <div class="header">Text</div>
    <div>
      <div class="row">Text</div>
      <div class="row">Text</div>
      <div class="row">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, this might help:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="header">Head</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="header">Head</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
    <div class="row">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.section .row:nth-child(even)
{
    background: red;
}
```